# Handling Quotation Syntax error when killing a process remotely (using SSH) through a script written in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, syntax-error

I have a python script file `foo.py` which has a function to delete a process remotely.

### Code Snippet

I use the following command:-

```
import os
def exit_app():
    os.system("ssh -tt nvidia@10.x.x.xxx "kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep 'start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash' | awk '{print \$2}')"")
    exit()
```

I receive the error that the syntax is invalid. It has something to do with the placement of the single and double quotation marks.

### Error:

```
  File "foo.py", line 2
    os.system('ssh nvidia@10.x.x.xxx "kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep 'start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash' | awk '{print \$2}')"')
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

### Things I have tried:-

1. Verifying that the command:-

> ssh -tt nvidia@10.x.x.xxx "kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep 'start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash' | awk '{print \$2}')"

works perfectly when used in the terminal.

2. Tried the `'"`...`"'` approach, yet I receive the error:-

   os.system("ssh -tt nvidia@10.5.3.157 '""kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep 'start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash' | awk '{print \$2}')"'"")

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

How should I fix this line then?

```
os.system("ssh -tt nvidia@10.x.x.xxx "kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep 'start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash' | awk '{print \$2}')"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `os.system`; use `subprocess` instead, and eliminate the (or rather, one) shell from the equation.

```
import subprocess


def exit_app():
    subprocess.call(
        ['ssh',
         '-tt',
         'nvidia@10.x.x.xxx',
         "kill $(ps -aux | awk '/start_with_nn_obj_detection.bash/ {print $2}')"
        ])
    exit()
```

If `pkill` is available on the remote host, though, you can simply run something like

```
subprocess.call(['ssh', '-tt', 'nvidia@10.x.x.x', 'pkill "start_with_n_obj_detection.bash"'])
```